# What is max current for goldpin connectors?

Tags: current, jumper

I'm designing a circuit which consists of two blocks on the same PCB. For testing I'd like to have an option of bypassing the second block and connect the first one to the output.

The standard solution would be to add goldpins with a jumper. The potential problem is that the output current could be as high as 6A. Can goldpins handle that? If not, what other inexpensive connectors could I use?

The voltage will be 12V.

Comment: "goldpin" is a pretty unspecific term.

Comment: Unanswerable without a connector datasheet.

Comment: You can always parallel multiple pin pairs to increase the current carrying capacity.

Comment: Unanswerable without a connector datasheet (as @Matt had already mentioned), or at least a photo of your connector.

Answer (score 8):

If you're referring to this sort of thing:
[image]

then, depending on the manufacturer, they could be rated for as much as 3A each. (The picture above is for an allegedly 2A rated part from 3M).
I wouldn't trust them for much over a few 100's of mA though, particularly if I didn't know exactly who made them and what their datasheet specifies.

Comment: I meant exactly this, 2.54mm raster pins. Seems that they are way to weak for my needs.

Comment: You could always parallel about 5 sets of these or so to get 5x the rated current capability...but that requires 5 jumpers, so not ideal. You could also use a power switch rated for the necessary current.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a 5mm pitch 2-point terminal block and a jumper like [this one](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/1693800000/281-1505-ND/385504) (or just piece of wire).

[image]

I don't see a current rating (so check) but I would imagine it's good for 10A or so.