# How much current/power can I expect a jumper cap to handle?

Tags: power, switches

Jumper caps are these things:

[image: these things]

I am making a general purpose PCB that utilizes the [ULN2803](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2803a.pdf?ts=1646554271799&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) IC, which is an array of darlington transistors. Its datasheet says that you can increase ampacity of the outputs by connecting them together. I would like to be able to be able to determine at a later time how many outputs to connect together for a particular application.

My first thought is to use a double row male header and jumpers to be able to hook up as many outputs together as I need:

[image: first thought]

Here,

- actuator 1 gets up to 2A,
- actuator 2 gets up to 1.5A,
- actuator 3 gets up to 0.5A

ULN2803A allows up to 50 V @ 500 mA per output. I'm realizing the loose-ish contact might make these jumpers a fire hazard.

What is the right way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: The uln2003 is also thermally limited so your idea of paralleling the outputs will work, but not as well as you’d like. The killer with the uln2003 is that it uses darlington transistors which give you a voltage drop of 2V further exacerbating the thermal issues. I’d suggest using a hc595 with logic level mosfets or maybe automotive parts that have protection and other features. As for jumpers, I wouldn’t suggest passing significant current through them.

Comment: Maybe use PCB fuse holders instead. 500mA you should be fine beyond that...ehhh...

Comment: Thanks @Kartman for the comment! Yeah, I'm used to using TIP120s and I (just this week) read this article (https://hackaday.com/2015/08/17/you-can-have-my-tips-when-you-pry-them-from-my-cold-dead-hands/) which at the end suggest that you can instead use a NTD4906N MOSFET instead. I wasn't aware of pitfalls of using darlington BJT transistors before). I like that the ULN2803A is one IC with 8 outputs. I'd be interested in a MOSFET based alternative.

Comment: Thanks @DKNguyen for your comment! That's definitely better than my idea.

Comment: TI have their TPIC6B595 and other variants but you still need to be aware of the thermal limitations. Sometimes these requirements are implied in the datasheets rather than explicit. You always want to determine the loss and temperature rise of your devices when controlling significant currents. Easier to solve on paper rather than finding out your devices melt and die.

Comment: @Kartman Wow, thank you so much! I think I read that you could parallel MOSFETs with the load being shared pretty well, so I assume you could do the same with that. Found for $3 per on amazon (https://amzn.to/3tCw3Ka), that's awesome!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is max current for goldpin connectors?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/138557/what-is-max-current-for-goldpin-connectors)

Comment: I wouldn't buy my electronics off Amazon tbh. Use some place reputable like Mouser, Digikey, Newark, etc. An actual electronics distributor.

Comment: I would imagine that the material and resistance matters a lot. That is gold plated -> gold flash -> tin/brass/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another data point, with fairly high spec materials (glass-filled PBT material but brass rather than phosphor-bronze for the contacts). Copyright as per watermark:

[image]

Personally, I'd be getting a bit nervous above 500mA each to 1A or so, depending on the temperature range and how many nearby are conducting that current. For example, if you believe the 20m\$\Omega\$ maximum resistance the power dissipation of 10 pairs (1" long) would be 1.8W which is quite a lot (and you have to add the heating from the traces etc.).

[Here](https://www.metz-connect.com/externalfiles/09200-71-BDGB00/916571.PDF) is another datasheet which gives 3A as the maximum. And [another](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811132212_BOOMELE-Boom-Precision-Elec-C5305_C5305.pdf) low-cost option from LCSC which again lists 3A.

Note also that there is no indication of whether the 3A applies over the entire temperature range or not. You might assume it does, but..

Comment: Gold plated switch contacts are only rated <2A for a reason. Thermal runaway ... oxidation is the likely to occur from initial resistance rise from temperature rise. Arhennius Law and MTBF stress factore suggest this will work with a short but happy life, (pun intended) but an unhappy ending if this good advise is exceeded

Answer (score 0):

A quality manufacturer SAMTEC lists their SNT shunt as 4.3 Amps, with a caevet of 1 pin powered per row.

Others may be much lower due to construction or material.

Also keep in mind the rated current for your header. You have to keep that in mind.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you for your answer, @Passerby. Yes, I imagine the materials in the header must also be rated for the current/temperature. I'll mark this as the accepted answer if there are no better alternative answers.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to solve this problem is to choose an SMT FET that can handle 10A cheaply and use only 2A to stay cool with logic level control.